# SharePoint Designer showing error while publishing the workflow of Backup and Restored site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

I cannot publish custom event workflows when **restores** site collection from another environment.

> Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run.
>
> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityValidationException: Workflow XAML  failed due to the following errors:
> Cannot create unknown type'{clr-namespace:SharePoint.Converter.PDF.SP2013}

Is there any option to resolve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is simple solution. But i want to know how I resolved it.

The below three lines resolved my problem.
I tried to reactive site feature of my custom event. But I cannot.
Use below code i resolved my issue.

**To Get the guid/name of site feature use below code:**

> Get-SPSite "http://sitecollectionurl" | Get-SPWeb -Limit ALL |%{ Get-SPFeature -Web $_ } | Select DisplayName,ID -Unique

**Disabling site feature use below code:**

> Disable-SPFeature -identity "Feature Display Name / ID" -URL "http://siteurl" -Force

**Enabling site feature use below code:**

> Enable-SPFeature  -identity "Feature Display Name / ID" -URL "http://siteurl" -Force

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the workflow in SharePoint designer?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Remove old workflow instances in the list. Go to the list->click “workflow settings” and select “workflow settings” in the ribbon->click “Remove, Block, or Restore a Workflow”->Remove the workflow instance.
2. Clear SharePoint configuration cache according to the article below.

[Clearing the SharePoint Configuration Cache.](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/clearing-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache/)

3. Clear SharePoint designer cache according to the article below.

[How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/)

4. Restart SharePoint server.

More reference:

[SharePoint Designer: Errors were found when compiling the workflow.](https://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/sharepoint-designer-errors-found-compiling-workflow/)

Comment: No luck. Yes those workflow created in SharePoint Designer. The problem is with the site collection which i restored. Because i tried with new site collection in the same server, i can publish the workflow there without any error.

Answer (score 0):

From a front-end perspective - my team and I don't have access to servers and/or central administration. I tried many of the front-end solutions but the only thing that worked was recreating the workflow. The workflow was long and complex but I

1. created my variables first
2. copy and pasted all the steps from the broken workflow to the new one.  I proceeded to publish the workflow and delete the broken workflow.